# IOS: Handling In-App Purchase Receipt Verification Failure

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I integrated in-app purchases with my ios app. But the problem was some times Apple returns "Invalid response data" after in-app purchase receipt verification against itunes server. I do not know why?. Also this is happening only for few users not for all. What was the actual problem here does any one know or facing this issue?. Also when the receipt verification failed does apple will charge for that purchase or no?.

Here my server side code to verify the purchased receipt against ituens server:

```
    <?php

        $devmode = FALSE; //TRUE; // change this to TRUE  testing against sandbox

        $receiptdata        = $_POST['receiptdata'];    
        $email_id           = base64_decode($_POST['user_email_id']);
        $pwd                = $_POST['pwd'];

        if($devmode)
        {
            $appleURL = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";

        }
        else
        {
            $appleURL = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";       
        }

        try {
            $receipt = json_encode(array("receipt-data" => $receiptdata));
            $response_json = do_post_request($appleURL, $receipt); 
            $response = json_decode($response_json);

            if (!is_object($response)) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid response data');
            }

            if (!isset($response->status) || $response->status != 0) 
            {           
                throw new Exception('Invalid receipt');
            }

            if($response->{'status'} == 0)
            {
                echo 'receipt verification success';

            } else {

            } 
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            eecho 'exception got: ' . $ex->getMessage();
            exit(0);
        }
function do_post_request($endpoint, $postData, $optional_headers = null)
{
        // create the cURL request
        $ch = curl_init($endpoint);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

        // execute the cURL request and fetch response data
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $errno    = curl_errno($ch);
        $errmsg   = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // ensure the request succeeded
        if ($errno != 0) {
            throw new Exception($errmsg, $errno);
        }

        return $response;
}
    ?>
```

Any help that must be appreciated.

Thanks,
-loganathan

Comment: show the codes & possible error codes please

Comment: I just updated the server code. Please check it. I am using mkstorekit 4 on my ios client side.